# How to copy files from one Google Drive Account to another programatically?

Tags: file-transfer, google-drive

I'm currently on a managed Google Drive account with unlimited storage. However, my organization is going to close the account soon, so I need a way to copy all my files out. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rclone copy remote-1:folder_to_copy_from remote:folder_to_copy_to --verbose=3 --ignore-existing`, with `remote-1` being the remote drive you want to copy from.

Since `rclone` doesn't play nice with duplicates, while Google Drive supports it, you can use `rclone dedupe first remote:folder_to_copy_to --verbose=3`

Check that all the files have been transferred with `rclone check remote-1:folder_to_copy_from remote:folder_to_copy_to --size-only --one-way --missing-on-dst A.txt`